# How do you compile vlc-nox

Tags: vlc, configure

I am trying to compile vlc 2.2.1 for a headless server but it keeps failing on ld cannot find lgl.

I have added all the switches i can think off to pass this:

```
--without-x
--disable-xcb
```

Etc. but everything i add still creates the same result.

Noting in ./configure --help says anything about disabling opengl.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm curious too (although I haven't tried yet, just exploring the possibility)

Comment: i did, i had to compile mesa for the libgl library. after mesa was installed i was able to continue the compile. but no i have not figured out a way to compile just libvlc without mesa